# Which WiFi module is able to host a custom web UI and can act as a station and AP?

Tags: wifi

I am an Arduino beginner. I am searching for a WiFi module that can act as a station and access point. It should have a external antenna.

I need to upload a script that starts a web server, so I can host my custom UI where the user can enter his WLAN credentials. After the credentials are set, it should try to connect to that WLAN like in the example script below, from a YouTube video.

I've [tried the ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/95194/esp8266-where-to-find-pin-assignment-guide-for-uploading-code), but uploading my script also overwrote the firmware.

Someone suggested the "Wemos D1 mini", but it does not have a big antenna and the one that I found with an antenna on Amazon has really really [bad reviews](https://www.amazon.de/XTVTX-Antennenanschluss-esp8266-Serie-WiFi-Entwicklungsplatine-Entwicklungsplatine/dp/B09LCJJTBV/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=UKEWJ8KNAW8R&keywords=Mini%20WEMOS%20D1%20Pro-16%20Module%2B2.4G%20ESP8266%20Series%20WiFi%20Wireless%20Antenna%20Connector&qid=1705316236&sprefix=mini%20wemos%20d1%20pro-16%20module%2B2.4g%20esp8266%20series%20wifi%20wireless%20antenna%20connector%2Caps%2C69&sr=8-1).

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

struct settings {
  char ssid[30];
  char password[30];
} user_wifi = {};

void setup() {
  EEPROM.begin(sizeof(struct settings) );
  EEPROM.get(0, user_wifi);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(user_wifi.ssid, user_wifi.password);
  byte tries = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    if (tries++ > 30) {
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
      WiFi.softAP("Setup Portal", "mrdiy.ca");
      break;
    }
  }
  server.on("/", handlePortal);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}

void handlePortal() {
  if (server.method() == HTTP_POST) {
    strncpy(user_wifi.ssid, server.arg("ssid").c_str(), sizeof(user_wifi.ssid));
    strncpy(user_wifi.password, server.arg("password").c_str(), sizeof(user_wifi.password));
    user_wifi.ssid[server.arg("ssid").length()] = user_wifi.password[server.arg("password").length()] = '\0';
    EEPROM.put(0, user_wifi);
    EEPROM.commit();
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>Wifi Setup</title><style>*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;}body{margin:0;font-family:'Segoe UI',Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,'Noto Sans','Liberation Sans';font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5;color:#212529;background-color:#f5f5f5;}.form-control{display:block;width:100%;height:calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);border:1px solid #ced4da;}button{border:1px solid transparent;color:#fff;background-color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff;padding:.5rem 1rem;font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.5;border-radius:.3rem;width:100%}.form-signin{width:100%;max-width:400px;padding:15px;margin:auto;}h1,p{text-align: center}</style> </head> <body><main class='form-signin'> <h1>Wifi Setup</h1> <br/> <p>Your settings have been saved successfully!<br />Please restart the device.</p></main></body></html>" );
  } else {
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>Wifi Setup</title> <style>*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;}body{margin:0;font-family:'Segoe UI',Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,'Noto Sans','Liberation Sans';font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5;color:#212529;background-color:#f5f5f5;}.form-control{display:block;width:100%;height:calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);border:1px solid #ced4da;}button{cursor: pointer;border:1px solid transparent;color:#fff;background-color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff;padding:.5rem 1rem;font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.5;border-radius:.3rem;width:100%}.form-signin{width:100%;max-width:400px;padding:15px;margin:auto;}h1{text-align: center}</style> </head> <body><main class='form-signin'> <form action='/' method='post'> <h1 class=''>Wifi Setup</h1><br/><div class='form-floating'><label>SSID</label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='ssid'> </div><div class='form-floating'><br/><label>Password</label><input type='password' class='form-control' name='password'></div><br/><br/><button type='submit'>Save</button><p style='text-align: right'><a href='https://www.mrdiy.ca' style='color: #32C5FF'>mrdiy.ca</a></p></form></main> </body></html>" );
  }
}
```

Comment: why is overwritten firmware a problem? why do you want a big antenna?

Comment: 1. If I override the firmware, then my device does not respond to AT commands and the wifi does not work at all.
2. To be able to transmit and receive data over a bigger distance, at least 20 meters.

Comment: the wifi not working isn't related to the firmware. but that is a separate question.

Comment: Thx, I will ask another question then.

Comment: About the bad reviews: A lot of them complain about the necessity to desolder a 0Ohm SMD resistor for using the external antenna. Maybe you can find a similar kit with higher quality and without that desoldering job at a more reputable seller. As you seem to be located in germany, maybe reichelt or conrad, or internationally mouser. Haven't searched them for such a kit, but the quality on amazon is often the same as buying clones directly from china over aliexpress or similar.

Comment: @chrisl, yes and not only that, they also replaced a diode with a 0 Ohm resistor which can destroy the USB slot of your PC. I also made the experience that amazon more and more becomes like wish. The sellers also buy 5 star reviews by trying to bribe users with money / gift cards. I will search on another shop, thx

Comment: 20 meters doesn't require any external antenna.

Comment: @Delta_G well, obviously It depends how many obstacles are in the way and how far the router is away. In my case the device will be put a few meters underground inside of a well, so I need a external antenna which I can place more at the top.

Comment: What do you mean depends on how far the router is away.  You said it was 20 meters.  You didn't mention anything about any well.

Comment: "uploading my script also overwrote the firmware" well, yeah... You're replacing the firmware, so obviously you can't have AT commands anymore.

Comment: @Delta_G so you automatically assumed that there are no obstacles in the way at all, only because I mentioned the distance is 20 meters? Thats a weird conclusion.

Comment: @dda is there a way to upload a sketch without also replacing the firmware?

Comment: I think the thing that you are not understanding is that the sketch and firmware are the same thing.  You only get one program on there.  The firmware is like a sketch that is preloaded and responds to AT commands.  You can write a program that also responds to AT commands or does any other thing you want.  But you cannot replace the program on the chip and then expect to still be able to use it.

Comment: @Black - I assumed nothing.  You didn't say there were any obstacles.  It's foolish to ask for help with something and then hide information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer some of the misunderstandings, though this is not really a full answer, since I currently don't know what the exact problem is.

First some terms:

- **Firmware**: A firmware is a program running on a device. What we refer to as firmware is commonly the result of the compiled code, so a program in machine language. (Though sometimes people talk about firmware and mean the firmware code, which is not compiled at that time). In the world of microcontrollers, a firmware runs directly on a microcontroller's hardware (as opposed to a PC, where there is an OS in between). Thus only 1 firmware can run on the microcontroller at any given time. You cannot upload multiple firmwares to a microcontroller at the same time. Thus uploading a new one will overwrite the previous one.
- **Sketch**: This is the Arduino term for your programs code. When you compile your sketch, the compiler will translate your code into assembler and then into machine language. The resulting file can then be uploaded to the microcontroller, where it overwrites the previous content of the flash memory.
- **SDK**: A Software Development Kit is a set of code that provides easy to use access to important functionalities. The Arduino framework itself can be called a SDK. It provides easy to use access for commonly used microcontroller functionality, like digital and analog inputs. If you program an ESP through the Arduino IDE, it will have a copy of the ESP SDK, which gives easier access to complex things like Wifi handling. This ESP SDK comes from the company that makes the ESPs: Espressif. If someone wants to write a program for an ESP, like a firmware that speaks AT commands over serial that someone will get the ESP SDK from Espressif.
- **AT firmware**: The AT firmware is not really different to your own program that you write/compile in the Arduino IDE. It uses the ESP SDK to handle things like Wifi. And it listens on the ESPs serial port for AT commands and reacts to them. You can write your own AT firmware, if you want to. This type of firmware is to provide simpler microcontrollers without Wifi hardware a network connection through Wifi. The simple microcontroller can send AT commands over serial to control the Wifi connection. Though this is of course inefficient and limited. It can be good to incorporate Wifi into an existing project, though when you try to do more complex stuff it is often better to ditch the simpler microcontroller and do everything directly on the ESP with your own custom firmware. No need for AT commands then.

> why the WiFi and AT commands are not working anymore after uploading a sketch

As described above, you have created and uploaded your own firmware, by writing a sketch for the ESP in the Arduino IDE and uploading it. That program overwrites the one that was previously saved on the ESP. Thus the AT firmware is gone now. If you want to restore it, I'm sure you can find a fitting one for your board online and upload that again.

Though from what you have written so far it seems to me that you don't really need an AT firmware. Programming a custom portal for Wifi credentials is something where you need your own firmware anyway. You are now sitting at the place of the AT firmware with your own program. You can tell it what to do by writing the corresponding code.

> Which WiFi module is able to host a custom web UI and can act as a station and AP?

Every ESP board is capable of that as far as I know. Though I haven't seen an AT firmware yet that would support setting up a custom web UI. So you would need to write your own firmware.

> Someone suggested the "Wemos D1 mini", but it does not have a big antenna and the one that I found with an antenna on Amazon has really really bad reviews.

Most ESP boards are not made with an external antenna as a priority. Even the ones with a socket for an external antenna might require some work to set them from internal to external antenna (like desoldering a resistor). You might be able to find one that doesn't require this. The Wemos D1 mini pro unfortunately requires the desoldering of the 0Ohm resistor. That is set by the manufacturer, so any reseller would do the work themselves. Not many will do that.

I cannot help you with finding such a board, as I don't know one (didn't need an external antenna yet). I would also just Google it.

And for better quality you need to go to reputable sources. Amazon is often just as a bad gamble as directly buying from China, AliExpress or similar. If you buy there, expect the quality to be rather low and some boards might even be broken. Sometimes that is OK, sometimes not.

Note: I'm really not an expert in RF, but honestly I would be surprised if connecting the antenna via a multiple meter-long cable wouldn't impact signal strength significantly. The ESP Wifi hardware is probably not built for driving the charge into such a long antenna. If this is the case it might be better to rethink your project design. You could put the ESP on top of the well (easily in reach of the Wifi network) and connect whatever you have down in the well from there. Or you could use another microcontroller handling the things in the well, connecting to the ESP via cable. Or if you absolutely need Wifi to connect down there, you might use an extender at the top of the well (can also be done by an ESP, if you don't want a full Wifi extender there). This very much depends on your exact requirements, so only a few ideas here.

---

Also I've noticed that in your `handlePortal()` function you are copying the SSID and password into the `user_Wifi` struct, but you are not actually changing the Wifi status. I would expect the code to do a change from AP to Station mode or reconnecting to the new Wifi.

You are saving the credentials into EEPROM (which is just flash on an ESP) and retrieving it on the next startup. I've made that error many times myself: when the expected Wifi network from the ESP doesn't show up, are you sure that there are no valid Wifi credentials saved from your previous run?

---

I hope that this helps you a bit.

Comment: "The ESP wifi hardware is probably not build for driving the charge into such a long antenna".  This is what I found with the ESP-07.  The losses in the cable far outweighed the gain from the antenna.  In the end it worked much better with the built in ceramic antenna, even when the antenna lead was kept to just a few cm.

Comment: So the SDK is permanent on the ESP and can't get overridden by flashing the flash memory?

Comment: No, the SDK is a software component on your PC, that is referenced by your own sketch (whenever you use Wifi in there for example). When you compile your own sketch,  the compiler also compiles the relevant parts of the SDK and puts both into one single binary, which then can be uploaded to the ESP. The SDK is needed when compiling a program for the ESP to access its special functions (like Wifi), so that the compiler knows how the calls to them should look like.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful informations @chrisl, I appreciate it